# Import .docx contents into MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word, docx

I began writing a docx document to do a project of mine. 
Recently, I realized that it would be easier to manage that data if it was in a database. 
So, I wanted to import that data into MS Access automatically, to avoid copying and pasting the data manually.

Is there anyway to do it? I have only encontered ways of opening Word application via Access. I also know that docx has a XML structure, so I imagine if I can open that structure, it would be easy to do a parser in VBA

Comment: Getting the XML is trivial - just open the .docx with a zip program and extract the "word" subfolder. Whether this will actually be useful is another question...

Comment: Will this be a one-time import of information from a single .docx file? Also, is the information in a table within the Word document?

Comment: Yes, please provide more information about the what and why you need to store content of a Word document. That's the only way anyone can provide closely targeted suggestions.

Comment: The docs just have text. They are songs. So some bigger and other smaller. My ideia was to extract that info to a single table where title and lyrics would be the fields (along with an ID). I would be importing X docx files that have this format, has the process would always be the same, just diferent paths to the various files.

Comment: Answered @CindyMeister

Comment: So you have multiple files that contain the title and the lyrics? Is the title on the first line by itself?

Comment: So, your table would have ID, title, lyrics and file path to the document? It can certainly be done. The major question remaining is: Do you expect to use the database to re-create these documents? Or is it more a tool for finding existing documents? If the former, capturing the WordOpenXML would make sense. If the latter, then better to transfer the pure text, which you'll be able to read in the database.

Comment: And once you get into the actual coding, Jeff's question becomes relevant: how are your documents STRUCTURED so that a program can be certain of extracting the data reliably?

Comment: The idea is that I have x documents with songs on it. Then I import that data into the database. Then I don't care anymore about the documents as the info is all that I want. Then I will use reports and the such to prepare that information for printing, so the documents are only important as long as their information is not in my database.

Comment: @CindyMeister my tables only have title and lyrics per music, not anything else.

Comment: You said yourself "(along with ID)" and "...just different paths to the various files". But you don't really answer the QUESTION in my previous comment, which is what we need to know.

Comment: @Jeff the only constant about the structure is that the title is always on a larger font that the lyrics (the possible values). I was thinking of just checking the size to understand what I was reading. Then as long as the font is the same, continue to write to the title/lyrics. When the font changes then verify by its value if it is lyrics or title. The musics are all sequencial so title1 lyrics1 title2 lyrics2 ....

Comment: I just expect to create a parser for docx documents

Comment: @CindyMeister did I answer your question? I just want to import the contents to the database. After that no more docx docs anymore.

Comment: I hadn't see the answers to my other questions because you didn't "tag" me on it. It would be useful for you to click "Edit" under your question and include the relevant information from these comments. Then we can delete the comments and see everything we need in one place...

Comment: How much experience do you have working with XML? Working with the .NET Framework / Visual Studio? Working with ZIP files? Do you have to retain the *formatting* of what's in the documents?

Comment: I have experience with XML and .net Framework. I am a computer science major. Never worked programatically with ZIP files. The formating must be kept. @CindyMeister

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two basic ways information can be taken out of a Word document and put into an Access database: automating the Word object model using VBA code running in either Word or Access OR extracting the WordOpenXML that makes up the Word document. You indicate you lean towards the second option.

Here, again, there are a number of approaches available:

- Use VBA in Word or Access to extract the WordOpenXML of the document open in the Word application user interface.
- Use VBA in Access together with non-VBA tools to "crack open" the Zip file and extract the XML.
- Use the tools available in the .NET Framework to extract the content of the ZIP file and write it to Access using an OLE DB connection.

I understand your goal is to be able to recreate the document at a later point for printing, so you want to preserve all the formatting. In addition, you want to be able to read the content from within Access.

I believe this will require a minimum of four fields in the Access table:

1. ID
2. Title
3. Text of song
4. The complete WordOpenXML for re-creating the document

You don't mention (4) in the discussion and problem description, but if you want to store the formatting AND you want to be able to read the content I believe this is necessary. While WordOpenXML is "readable", there's a lot of mark-up in there which doesn't make reading *comfortable*.

All things being equal, I'd go for either VBA working on the open Word document or the .NET approach, using the Open XML SDK ([free download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425) .NET library you can reference in Visual Studio and distribute with solutions).

One important thing to keep in mind is storing the Word Open XML in the database. Unless something has changed in Access, you can't store the ZIP file - you need a "streamable" format. That would be the OOXML OPC flat-file format.

When you read the WordOpenXML from a document using VBA, that's what you get, which is why that would be an option for me. The Open XML SDK doesn't have that option, but there is code available from [Eric White's blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericwhite/2008/09/29/transforming-open-xml-documents-to-flat-opc-format/) for doing this.

When you later want to recreate and print the document it should be enough to stream the WordOpenXML to a file with the .xml extension. Or you could convert it back to a docx zip file (same blog).

Comment: Thanks for the reply @CindyMeister ! I would lean towards the second approach. So if I understood correctly first I extract the XML from the docx using a 7zip or smth. Then I parse that XML via VBA?

Comment: @user2934164 Yes... The question is what you're going to do with it. It's no simple matter, converting that information to the OPC flat file format, which is the only way that makes sense for saving enough information to recreate the document from data stored in your database.

Comment: I was thinking of using something like Cristal Reports to handle the printing side

Comment: I have no experience with Crystal Reports and have no idea whether they can process WordOpenXML?

Comment: In the end, I realized there was a problem with using normal text in Access. It has no support for using bolds or italics and other text features which are used when writing these lyrics. As such I use OLE Objects and will copy paste the lyrics into the DB.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much what I was getting at and why I suggested four fields. If you save the WordOpenXML that can always be "streamed" back to a Word document for printing, while you can simply read the text (without the formattting) in the data base for reference purposes.